FirebaseStorage 10.24.0 Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'any StorageProvider'
I am using FirebaseStorage 10.24.0 in iOS project Xcode 15.2
I am getting following compilation error:
Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'any StorageProvider'
Pods/FirebaseStorage/Storage.swift
  /// Creates an instance of `Storage`, configured with a custom `FirebaseApp`. `StorageReference`s
  /// generated from a resulting instance will reference files in the Firebase project
  /// associated with custom `FirebaseApp`.
  /// - Parameter app: The custom `FirebaseApp` used for initialization.
  /// - Returns: A `Storage` instance, configured with the custom `FirebaseApp`.
  @objc(storageForApp:) open class func storage(app: FirebaseApp) -> Storage {
    guard let provider = ComponentType<StorageProvider>.instance(for: StorageProvider.self,
                                                                 in: app.container) else {
      fatalError("No \(StorageProvider.self) instance found for Firebase app: \(app.name)")
    }
    return provider.storage(for: Storage.bucket(for: app))
  }



On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.  If you feel the image helps, include it, but please don't assume that everyone finds it easy or possible to deal with code in an image.

Your first move should be to update Xcode (and FirebaseStorage) to the latest version(s).

Well any solution after so many days??

I had the same problem. Initially, I was using pod 'FirebaseStorage' but noticed that my other Firebase pods were specified like pod 'Firebase/Analytics'. Switching to pod 'Firebase/Storage' resolved the issue. Hopefully, this solution will work for you as well.
